# Update all element of an array in json postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

In my table I have a jsonb type column.
Example jsonb data:

```
{
   "id": "1", 
   "customer":[{"id": "1", "isPosted": "false"},{"id": "2","isPosted": "false"}]
}
```

Is it possible to update all element named isPosted to 'true'?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a monkey hack here - replace the value and use result as jsonb:

```
t=# with c(j) as (values('{"id": "1", "customer":[{"id": "1", "isPosted": "false"},{"id": "2","isPosted": "false"}]} '::jsonb))
select *,replace(j::text,'"isPosted": "false"','"isPosted": "true"')::jsonb from c;
-[ RECORD 1 ]------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
j       | {"id": "1", "customer": [{"id": "1", "isPosted": "false"}, {"id": "2", "isPosted": "false"}]}
replace | {"id": "1", "customer": [{"id": "1", "isPosted": "true"}, {"id": "2", "isPosted": "true"}]}
```

finally you [can do it the right way](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
t=# with c(j) as (values('{"id": "1", "customer":[{"id": "1", "isPosted": "false"},{"id": "2","isPosted": "false"}]} '::jsonb))
, n as (select jsonb_set(e,'{isPosted}'::text[],'true'),j from c, jsonb_array_elements(j->'customer') with ordinality a (e,o))
select jsonb_set(j,'{customer}'::text[],jsonb_agg(jsonb_set)) from n group by j;
                                        jsonb_set
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"id": "1", "customer": [{"id": "1", "isPosted": true}, {"id": "2", "isPosted": true}]}
(1 row)
```